# unable to transform value for property path "tagname". Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working with two ManyToMany related entities, namely `category` and `tag`.

The entity `Tag`(relevant details):

```
/**
 * 
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tagname", type="string")
 */
protected $tagname;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="tags")
 */
protected $categories;
```

The entity Category(relevant details):

```
/**
 * 
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CategoryName", type="string",length=200)
 */
protected $categoryname;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="categories")
 */
protected $tags;
```

I have a form with a select-input(CategoryType) and a multiple select-input(TagType) fields. Both the fields are EntityType fields. The TagType is embedded inside the CatgoryType.

For this I am not able to utilise the `cascade=persist` functionality and am adding the submitted tags manually inside my controller. On submission the form data gets persisted in the database without any issues.

The problem is, after submission, when I fetch the submitted category(and the associated tags) in my controller, and pass it to the form, I get this error - `Unable to transform value for property path "tagname": Expected a Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection object.`

The var_dump result of the fetched category object(`var_dump($category->getTags()->getValues());`) gives me an array of the associated Tag objects, with the property `protected 'tagname' => string 'tag1'`.

From what I understand `Interface Collection` is quite similar to a php array and My guess is that the `tagname` field expects all the `tagname`s in an ArrayCollection or Collection object format. I am not sure whether what is the specific difference.

However I am still clueless how do I pass the already persisted category object in my form.

Here are the `categoryname`  and `tags` field in the `CategoryType`:

```
    $builder->add('categoryname', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Category',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC');
},
        'choice_label' => 'categoryname',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
        'label' => 'Choose Category',
    ));
    $builder->add('tags', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => TagType::class,
        'allow_add' => true,
        'by_reference' => false,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ));
```

Here is the embedded `tagname` field in the `TagType`:

```
    $builder->add('tagname', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Tag',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                    ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC');
},
        'choice_label' => 'tagname',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => true,
        'label' => 'Choose Tags',
    ));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption was wrong, I need to either make `tagname` field an array or create a ManyToOne or ManyToMany relationship with any other entity so it can be an arraycollection. Only then it is possible to use tagname as a multiple select field.

```
/**
 * 
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="tagname", type="array")
 */
protected $tagname;
```

or

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SOME_ENTITY", mappedBy="SOME_PROPERTY")
 */
protected $tagname;
```

or

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SOME_ENTITY", mappedBy="SOME_PROPERTY")
 */
protected $tagname;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to rid off `'multiple' => true` in embedded form. This worked for me.

Comment: I love the clarity of the Symfony error message, so straightforward :D

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem where my EntityType form element gave me this error message:

Unable to reverse value for property path 'my_property' Expected an array.

Setting multiple to false would make the implementation useless, so a better option for me was to set the empty_data to an empty array:

```
 "empty_data"         => [],
```

In your case you might be able to solve the problem by setting the empty_data to a Collection, something like this will probably work:

```
 "empty_data"         => new ArrayCollection,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it (from source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNCpj4otnrc):

[image]

[image]

[image]

***And here is a text version of this image #1, the reason I did not add text because it was hard to read when the format is not proper!

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Post;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class PostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Etner the title here',
                    'class' => 'custom_class'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Enter teh description here',
                ]
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'App\Entity\Category'
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Post::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

***And here is a text version of this image #2, the reason I did not add text because it was hard to read when the format is not proper!

```
class FormController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/form", name="form")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $post = new Post(); // exit('this');
    /*$post->setTitle('welcome');
    $post->setDescription('description here');*/
    $form = $this->createForm(PostType::class, $post, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('form'),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ]);

    // handle the request
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
    {
        // var_dump($post); die();
        // save to database
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('form/index.html.twig', [
        'postaform' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score -1):

The exception thrown is pretty explicit, and the problem is probably here:

```
$builder->add('tagname', EntityType::class, array()
```

According to your `Tag` entity, `Tag::$tagname` is not an entity collection, it's a string. You should add the property with

```
$builder->add('tagname', TextType::class, array()
```

shouldn't you ?

Comment: Thank you for the input. However I do need to use ChoiceType to create a multiple input-select field. So using TextType is not the right answer for the problem.